# Discord.py get message from DM

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I try to make my bot to get message from DM using this syntax:

```
for wolf in wolf_list_id:
   poll_message = await self.client.get_message(wolf, react_message.id)
```

The wolf contains the id of user, but the get_message syntax can't take the id from wolf. Any ideas?

Comment: What exactly is this supposed to do?  You're looking in private channels for a message with the same id as another message `react_message`?

Answer (score 0):

like said the doc, the [`client.get_message`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.get_message) methods must take as parameter an channel object and an id.
In case of DM channel, you can pass an `user` or `member` object.

For get an user by id, you can use [`client.get_user_info`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.get_message) methods:

```
user = await client.get_user_info("123456789")
```

And after, with your `user`object, you can get message with ID

```
message = await client.get_message(user, "135792468")
```

So, for fix your code, if wolf is a string id, you can use this following code:

```
for wolf in wolf_list_id:
    user = await self.client.get_user_info(wolf)
    poll_message = await self.client.get_message(user, react_message.id)
```