# Get message content from reply in DM

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I started making a little discord bot to give a key to people who request it. However, requirements changed and now I need to get a valid email from people who want one. I'm not sure how to get a reply in a DM.

I saw [Discord.py get message from DM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53371935/discord-py-get-message-from-dm)

But I don't really have client.get_user_info() or something?

```
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')


@bot.command(pass_context =True, no_pm=True, name='key', help="I give you a key. you're welcome", )



async def key_giver(ctx):
    commandTime = str(datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))


##check if you're PMing bot
    elif isinstance (ctx.channel, discord.DMChannel):
        print(ctx.message)
        await ctx.author.send(keyArray[0])

    else:
        response = "Hello my friend. I give you a key for a game. This is my purpose. Please enter your email!"



    ##Send key via PM 
    await ctx.author.send(response)
```

Printing ctx.message is

`<Message id=620538695124254720 channel=<DMChannel id=614377525417738240 recipient=<User id=605223566371192852 name='aon' discriminator='5906' bot=False>> type=<MessageType.default: 0> author=<User id=605223566371192852 name='aon' discriminator='5906' bot=False>>`

I'm really not sure. I'm just stupid, please don't yell at me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Client.wait_for`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.wait_for) to wait for the message and use its results.  You already have the `User` object (`ctx.author`), so you can get the channel to listen for from [`User.dm_channel`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.User.dm_channel).  I'm re-using the `message_check` function [from this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55812442/6779307) to generate the check

```
# Send them a message in a DM
await ctx.author.send("Please give an email address")

# Wait for a response
response = await bot.wait_for('message', check=message_check(channel=ctx.author.dm_channel))
```

Comment: Hmm. The respose just returns the same object kinda thing

`<Message id=620845388961808406 channel=<DMChannel id=614377525417738240 recipient=<User id=605223566371192852 name='aon' discriminator='5906' bot=False>> type=<MessageType.default: 0> author=<User id=605223566371192852 name='aon' discriminator='5906' bot=False>>
`

Not the actual content of the message?

Comment: You can access the content through `response.content`